# Simplest way to format pandas display function output with black borders lines between every line and column as a grid on Jupyter note

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

When printing data frame with `display` command pandas print only one border after column names and separe rows just with a slightly different color, it make hard to read data, how can format output with black
thick borders like excel. Im using Jupyter. There is doc on how to change cell color but cant found nothing about border color.
Need borders between columns AND rows.

Comment: You could try another library like `tabulate` and a style like 'fancy_grid': https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/

Comment: @ALollz It solves the problem, thanks.

Comment: @ALollz Would be great do it with display, I discovered tabulate mess all when it has hundreds columns.